# about the validity of the json message

Tags: json

I am wondering why the following is not a valid json

```
{ test : event}
```

but

```
{ "test" : "event" }
```

is a valid one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because in JSON, fields are declared in quotes (so it's `"test"` and not `test`), and the only data types a field can store are: number, string, boolean, array, object (that is, another JSON object), or null. `event` isn't any of those things, but `"event"` is a string, which is a valid value type. Those are just the rules of JSON.

[You should read up on JSON.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON)